# How to remove all special character codes and emojis dynamically in python?

Tags: python, regex, unicode

Guys I have a problem to remove special character codes and emojis from a text in python, the normal regex and replace don't work, I found out that the codes come with 4 bars, example "\\\\u2019\\"

The only solution that worked was:

imput string = commercial "\u2013" is a perennial sector

```
text = re.sub('"\\\\u2013\\"',"–",re.sub('"\\\\\u2014\\"',"—",re.sub('"\\\\\u2015\\"',"―",re.sub('"\\\\\u2017\\"',"‗",re.sub('"\\\\u2018\\"',"‘",re.sub('"\\\\u2019\\"',"’",re.sub('"\\\\u201A\\"',"‚",re.sub('"\\\\u201B\\"',"‛",re.sub('"\\\\u201C\\"',"“",re.sub('"\\\\u201D\\"',"”",re.sub('"\\\\u201E\\"',"„",re.sub('"\\\\u2020\\"',"†",re.sub('"\\\\u2021\\"',"‡",re.sub('"\\\\u2022\\"',"•",re.sub('"\\\\u2026\\"',"…",re.sub('"\\\\u2030\\"',"‰",re.sub('"\\\\u2032\\"',"′",re.sub('"\\\\u2033\\"',"″",re.sub('"\\\\u2039\\"',"‹",re.sub('"\\\\u203A\\"',"›",re.sub('"\\\\u203C\\"',"‼",re.sub('"\\\\u203E\\"',"‾",re.sub('"\\\\u2044\\"',"⁄",re.sub('"\\\\u204A\\"',"⁊", df2))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

it was ugly but it worked, however I need to put all possible special character codes and emojis, which are many.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to leave this dynamic code to consider all possible codes and emojis?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your text, please?

Comment: @corralien, i edit the question

Comment: When you print your string, does it the output: `'commercial \\u2013 is a perennial sector'`?

Comment: yes that's right, it only understands in replace when I put 4 bars \

Comment: 2014 and 2015 have five backslashes... You can express this better using raw strings, since that allows you to halve the number of backslashes you have: `r'\' == '\\'`

Answer (score 0):

Try `encode` / `decode`:

```
s = r'commercial \u2013 is a perennial sector'

print(s.encode().decode('unicode_escape'))

# Output:
commercial – is a perennial sector
```